# Can I extract a file or directory using the tar command and provide it a specific name I want it extracted as?

Tags: linux, tar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I extract a specific folder using tar to another folder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/289663/can-i-extract-a-specific-folder-using-tar-to-another-folder)

I am new to world of Linux and would like to know if I can extract a specific file or directory by giving it a new name or path. For example if my archive has the folders sample1, sample2 and sample3, I would like to be able to extract sample3 however as sample4. The same question applies to files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that you can accomplish this task.

1. tar has a `-s` option, defined as follows:

   > -s pattern
   >
   > Modify file or archive member names according to pattern.  The pattern has the format
   >   /old/new/[gps].  old is a basic regular expression.  If it doesn't apply, the pattern is
   >   skipped.  new is the replacement string of the matched part.  ~ is substituted with the
   >   match, 1 to 9 with the content of the corresponding captured group.  The optional trail-
   >   ing g specifies that matching should continue after the matched part and stopped on the
   >   first unmatched pattern.  The optional trailing s specifies that the pattern applies to
   >   the value of symbolic links.  The optional trailing p specifies that after a successful
   >   substitution the original path name and the new path name should be printed to standard
   >   error.

   You can run `tar xf <archive file> -s /sample3/sample4/` to achieve your desired result.
2. tar can extract files directly to standard output, after which you can use [the standard Unix file redirection operations](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) to direct the output into a file named whatever you want.

   Example: `tar xf <archive file> -O sample3 > sample4`

   Note that the "sample3" filename is not an argument to the `-O` parameter; it's being used by tar to limit extraction to just that file. If you did not specify `sample3`, then tar would extract every file in the archive and lump them into one big uncompressed output file.